# compile time Error in Analyzer in hibernate search

Tags: java, hibernate, solr, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm using Hibernate search first time. When I'm trying to add Analyzer, I get the compile time error -

```
incompatible types: java.lang.Class<org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<? extends org.apache.solr.analysis.TokenizerFactory>
```

As the error shows, I tried adding solr-core jar too as below, but seems it also doesn't contain the specified class:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my entity class:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.LowerCaseFilterFactory;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.ngram.NGramFilterFactory;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Analyzer;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.AnalyzerDef;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Indexed;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Parameter;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.TokenFilterDef;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.TokenizerDef;

@Entity
@Table(name = "hk_system_message_info")
@Indexed
@AnalyzerDef(name = "myanalyzer",
        tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = WhitespaceTokenizerFactory.class),
        filters = {@TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class), @TokenFilterDef(factory = NGramFilterFactory.class, params = { @Parameter(name = "maxGramSize", value = "1024") })})
public class HkMessageEntity implements Serializable {
...
}
```

The dependency which I've added for hibernate-search (Note: Other hibernate dependencies are added as per requirement, this is for search only):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

`Hibernate-Analyzer` was added automatically with this so I didn't add it separately.

I've no idea why the `FilterFactory` classes are not found in hibernate search jar. Also, I know at the back end, Hibernate uses Apache Lucene search. I saw in the source code too and `WhitespaceTokenFactory` extends `TokenFactory` class and still this error is shown.

Is there any other dependency that needs to be added? In the documents, I found this one only and added it. What's it that I'm missing?

Comment: I am not sure if it solves it, but you are adding the wrong lucene/solr version. Have a look at the [hibernate search dependencies](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-search-analyzers/4.5.1.Final) they are using 3.6.2 not 4.8.

Answer (score 0):

To use Apache Lucene 4.8 (or Solr of the same version) you need [Hibernate Search 5.0](http://hibernate.org/search/downloads/)

Also in this version, the Analyzers are no longer part of Solr but are distributed in the Lucene jars.

See also [The Hibernate Search Migration Guide](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateSearchMigrationGuide#jive_content_id_Hibernate_Search_5).

Alternatively to use Hibernate Search 4.x you should use Apache Lucene 3.6.x.